# Accesing filename passed to Fortran executable within its program

Tags: file, fortran

I am trying to create a Fortan program, which when compiled to an executable, can take a file as a parameter (e.g., progexe afile).

I need to code the program in such a way that the filename passed (afile) is available within the Fortran program. I cannot figure out how to do this.  I am using gfortran in MingW on windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [GET_COMMAND_ARGUMENT](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/GET_005fCOMMAND_005fARGUMENT.html). It works for me with gfortran 4.6.3. Example use:

```
PROGRAM Main
    IMPLICIT NONE
    CHARACTER(LEN=4096) :: FileName
    CALL GET_COMMAND_ARGUMENT(1, FileName)
    WRITE(*,*) 'Your file name is ', TRIM(FileName)
STOP
ENDPROGRAM
```

Compile and run:

```
brady@rocky:~/tmp$ gfortran -o gcatest gcatest.f90 
brady@rocky:~/tmp$ ./gcatest myfile.txt
 Your file name is myfile.txt
brady@rocky:~/tmp$
```